# need to capture bash command output

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to measure MySQL QPS (Queries per Second) for trending analysis.

```
mysqladmin -P3104 -rvi1 ex 2>&1 | grep Questions
```

I can't get the above into a text file using the following:

```
mysqladmin -P3104 -rvi1 ex 2>&1 | grep Questions > out.txt
```

or
    mysqladmin -P3104 -rvi1 ex 2>&1 | grep Questions | tee out.txt

I think `ex` might be interfering with the stdout/stderr redirection.
But I just need to capture the output into a file, I don't need to see screen output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2>&1 instead of 2&>1:

```
mysqladmin -P3104 -rvi1 ex 2>&1 | grep Questions > out.txt
```